# Provide 32x32 favicon to support application shortcuts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, images, google-chrome, favicon

I would like to see support for a 32x32 favicon like gmail does:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/images/2/gmail-icon.png" sizes="32x32">
```

So that when I pin SO (or any of the trilogy websites) to my taskbar it would look clear instead of blurry (see image below comparing gmail and SO):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use the apple touch icon which is extremely high res:

```
<head>     
<title>Stack Overflow</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://sstatic.net/so/all.css?v=4864b39b46cf"> 
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://sstatic.net/so/favicon.ico"> 
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://sstatic.net/so/apple-touch-icon.png">
```

apple-touch-icon.png, like so

[image]

Comment: OK but Google Chrome won't use that. You need to manually put the `<link rel="icon">` in your `head`. You could still link to the apple touch icon.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the sizes="32x32" thing is what determines if the icon will be scaled down or not. I added this into the tag for a site I am working on and now the icon is way better looking than it was before, with the same icon.