# Why can't I start a bounty on this question?

Tags: discussion, bounties

So I really like [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16640/add-a-copy-profile-to-sister-sites-button) and wanted it to get some more attention. I thought starting a bounty would be a great idea, but for some reason I'm not able to. It's been open for two days?

Is there some criteria that it doesn't meet that I'm over looking?

Comment: There is a "start a bounty" link. Can you even see it, even after clearing your cache?

Comment: @random: Nope. I can't see it in any of my browsers (Google Chrome, Firefox 4.01b, Safari 5, IE). I also tried it in all of their "porn" modes.

Comment: @random: Also just tried on my blackberry and I didn't see it either.

Comment: Is there a rep requirement for starting a bounty on other people's questions, perhaps? I can't say I've really kept up with the feature in detail...

Comment: @Jon: Same here. As much as I love the new bounty changes, they are quite hard to keep up with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess ... [you already have a bounty open](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51680/provide-32x32-favicon-to-support-application-shortcuts)...

The code reads, show the bounty link if

1. Its a question
2. Its not Closed / Locked or Deleted
3. It was created 2 days ago or before
4. **You do not have an open bounty**
5. You have more than 100 rep
6. You are not on a child meta site

Comment: Eureka! Man there are a lot of rules for the bounties.