# Can Place a Bounty on a Locked Q/A, but Can't Award It

Tags: bug, bounties, locked

A few days ago, I revisited the infamous [HTML Zalgo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) question. Seeing the "start a bounty" link, I clicked it. I ended up being able to place one on the question despite the entire Q/A post being locked.

[image: "The bounty expires in 3 days" message at the top of the question]

When I went to award the bounty, I get the confirmation popup, followed by an error message:

[image: "This post has been locked; locked posts can&#39;t be voted on"]

Also, there's a double HTML escape bug, too, reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382968).

Comment: This is intentional: per our FAQ [What is a "locked" post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post): *Users cannot award bounties to locked answers.*

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog That's fine, but I was still able to initiate the process. Per your own link: *"For locked questions, the following actions also cannot be performed: **Offering bounties**."*

Comment: The question merely has a comment lock, meaning the only interaction disabled on it is commenting, while all other interactions such as voting, answering, and setting bounties are still allowed. (The top of the FAQ post says it doesn't apply to comment locks.)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Ah, you're right. However, the double HTML entity escape is still there, though.

Comment: Just edit this to be solely about that issue and I'll remove my duplicate vote.

Comment: Previously a similar problem occurred 8 years ago: [HTML entities in "bounty expiring soon" notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244154/282094)

Comment: This post in question is only comment locked, so the duplicate doesn't apply here. One should be able to award a bounty when a post is only comment locked.

Comment: @Luuklag the real question is, which answer did the OP try to award it to? Was it [the infamous Zalgo answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2821954) which is also currently locked completely?

Comment: That would be a valid point @MetaAndrewT. If that's the case the duplicate is warranted.

Comment: @Luuklag Yes, the problem was that the OP tried to award the bounty to a locked _answer_. I wrote an [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1657509/find-bounties-that-ended-during-a-comment-only-lock) to find bounties deleted during a comment-only lock. Ironically, when I executed it on Stack Overflow, I found out that the OP here has actually [managed to award a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1732348/timeline#history_0d037866-4613-4083-bc40-13565863e34f) to another answer to the same question shortly before starting their current one.

Comment: This is answered in [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) Quoting: _"Regardless of the question's locked status, you can't award bounties to answers that are locked. However, if a locked answer meets the criteria for automatic awarding, it can receive an automatic award."_

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can users award existing bounties on questions that get historically locked? Do automatic awards still work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341823/282094)  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133739/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/56707/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304936/282094